# Genji's opening greeting

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

With the version 2.0 release and arrival of Genji, what is Genji's greeting (translated to English) in the opening video sequence after app launch?

Comment: Did you try to find it here: http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Genji/Quotes ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Genji says: `身を捨てても、名利は捨てず`
In ocidental letters it becomes this: `mi o sutetemo myouri wa sutezu`
The translation is: `Even if I sacrifice my body, I will never sacrifice my honor`

He says the same when selected in Overwatch.

Source: http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Genji/Quotes